# docker-compose exec web bundle exec rake db:migrateをするとCan't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) となってしまう

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql, docker, docker-compose

#### 前提・実現したいこと

RailsアプリにDockerを導入しようとしています。
エラーが起き、自力で解決できなかったので質問させていただきます。

現在ローカル側でdockerを起動しても以下のエラーが発生してしまいます。

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

ターミナルでdockerを起動させ `$ docker-compose exec web bundle exec rake db:migrate` のコマンドを叩いたところ以下のようなエラーが起きました。

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:45:in `rescue in new_client'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:39:in `new_client'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:23:in `mysql2_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `public_send'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:926:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:905:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:866:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:588:in `checkout'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:428:in `connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1128:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:327:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:283:in `connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:237:in `migrate'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:92:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

Caused by:
Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90:in `connect'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90:in `initialize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:40:in `new'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:40:in `new_client'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:23:in `mysql2_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `public_send'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:926:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:905:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:866:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:588:in `checkout'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:428:in `connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1128:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:327:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:283:in `connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:237:in `migrate'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:92:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

#### 試したこと

- [mysqlのsocketエラーでrailsアプリが起動できない](https://qiita.com/fujitora/items/d341c52706d1954cae28) などを参考にしながら、
  MySQLが起動できていることを確認。
- databe.ymlに以下を追記するも変化なし。

  ```
  socket: /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  ```

必要な情報等あればお答えします。
2日程度悩んでおります。お願い致します。(m1 macです。)

---

#### 該当のソースコード

▼Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.7

ENV RAILS_ENV=production

RUN wget --quiet -O - /tmp/pubkey.gpg https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs yarn
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./src /app
RUN bundle config --local set path 'vendor/bundle' \
    && bundle install

COPY start.sh /start.sh
RUN chmod 744 /start.sh
CMD ["sh", "/start.sh"]
```

▼docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
    db:
        image: mysql:8.0
        platform: linux/x86_64
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        volumes:
            - ./src/db/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    web:
        build: .
        command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
        volumes: 
            - ./src:/app
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        depends_on:
            - db
```

▼database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password: password
  host: db

development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: app_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['APP_DATABASE'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['APP_DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['APP_DATABASE_HOST'] %>
```

Answer (score 1):

回答いただきありがとうございました。
`environment`キーの`RAILS_ENV`という環境変数に`development`を入れることで解決しました。

▼docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
    db:
        image: mysql:8.0
        platform: linux/x86_64
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        volumes:
            - ./src/db/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    web:
        build: .
        command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
        volumes: 
            - ./src:/app
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        environment:
            RAILS_ENV: development #追加
        depends_on:
            - db
```

助かりました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

docker コンテナの web から db は仮想的に別のサーバーに見えてるはずなので

socket: /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

はかいちゃだめです

web から MySQL ホスト名は db という名前でみえるはずなので
ENV['APP_DATABASE'] に db という文字列が入ってるか確認してください

はいってなければ

```
<%= ENV['APP_DATABASE'] | 'db' %>
```

とかかくか docker-compose に

```
web:
  environment:
    APP_DATABASE: db
```

とか起動ユーザの bash_profile なり .env なりで環境変数セットする必要があります

Comment: 環境変数を設定し解決しました。ありがとうございました。